# Pandas, list.append or Google Analytics API is giving incorrect data formatting or response in Python

Tags: python, pandas, append, google-analytics-api

I have a list of tuples that contain date ranges, like so:

```
[('2012-01-01', '2012-01-25'),
 ('2012-01-26', '2012-02-20'),
 ('2012-02-21', '2012-03-16'),
 ('2012-03-17', '2012-04-11'),
 ('2012-04-12', '2012-05-06')...]

def pull_unsampled(date_list):

    df123 = []

    for start, end in date_list:

        df123.append(ga.read_ga(metrics, 
                    dimensions = "yearMonth", 
                    start_date = start,
                    end_date = end, 
                    account_id = account_id, profile_id = profile_id))
        print start, end

    return df123

pull_unsampled(unsampled_date_ranges)
```

In the above function I take the list of tuples and pass the start and end dates to a Google Analytics API request through Pandas.  I printed the start and end dates that are going through the for loop and the are printed exactly how they appear in the original list.  When I receive the response data, I am given dates that are not formatted like the input, infact I am given different dates.

```
[                                           visits  transactionsPerVisit  \
deviceCategory operatingSystem yearMonth                                  
desktop        (not set)       2020-12-01     137              0.000000   
               Chrome OS       2020-12-01      20              0.000000   
               Google TV       2020-12-01       5              0.000000   
               Linux           2020-12-01     363              0.275482   
               Macintosh       2020-12-01  111467              0.909686   
               Nintendo Wii    2020-12-01       2              0.000000   
               Playstation 3   2020-12-01       1              0.000000   
               SunOS           2020-12-01       3              0.000000   
               Windows         2020-12-01   98147              0.996464   
mobile         Android         2020-12-01    2976              0.302419   
               BlackBerry      2020-12-01    1051              0.000000   
               Nokia           2020-12-01       2              0.000000   
               Samsung         2020-12-01       1              0.000000   
               SymbianOS       2020-12-01       4              0.000000   
               Windows Phone   2020-12-01      46              0.000000   
               iPad            2020-12-01       2              0.000000   
               iPhone          2020-12-01   24754              0.379737   
               iPod            2020-12-01     331              0.000000   
tablet         Android         2020-12-01     189              0.529101   
               iPad            2020-12-01   24973              0.828895
```

For some reason the date range of `('2012-01-01', '2012-01-25')` returns improper dates for the yearMonth column above, but later responses appear correctly.  For example the last date range pull of `('2014-03-06', '2014-03-31')` give the following where yearMonth is show correctly:

```
                                          avgTimeOnSite  pageviewsPerVisit  
deviceCategory operatingSystem yearMonth                                    
desktop        (not set)       201403          1.127708           1.013683  
               Chrome OS       201403        159.150562           3.811236  
               Google TV       201403          0.000000           1.000000  
               Linux           201403        431.220165           8.705575  
               Macintosh       201403        219.625070           5.193008  
               Nintendo Wii    201403          0.000000           1.000000  
               Playstation 3   201403         65.000000           3.000000  
               Windows         201403        186.650353           4.077768  
               Xbox            201403          0.000000           1.000000  
mobile         (not set)       201403         51.151515           2.212121  
               Android         201403        143.776396           3.195142  
               BlackBerry      201403        132.644037           3.049541  
               Nokia           201403          0.400000           1.000000  
               Series40        201403          5.071429           1.214286  
               SymbianOS       201403          0.000000           1.000000  
               Windows Phone   201403        172.685446           3.305164  
               iOS             201403        126.005593           2.954413  
tablet         Android         201403        183.609062           3.746048  
               BlackBerry      201403        224.421053           3.789474  
               iOS             201403        217.915084           4.462462
```

Is this a bug in the list.append, pandas or the Google Analytics API? Is there something I can fix in my code to prevent these odd dates from being put in place of actual dates?

EDIT:

Here is just a simple call that returns the yearMonth data as it should for the same date range:

```
df = ga.read_ga(metrics, 
            dimensions = dimensions, 
            start_date = start_date,
            end_date = end_date, 
            account_id = account_id, profile_id = profile_id)

df
```

Returns as:

```
    visits
yearMonth   
201001   270094
201002   254034
201003   305295
201004   311824
201005   281570
201006   249348
201007   247005
201008   245882
201009   252296
201010   266417
201011   274349
201012   272913
201101   259959
201102   261080
201103
```

Comment: I noticed that you say "append" in your description, but I don't see it used in your code. I do see list.extend() used, though, so maybe that's what you mean. If you're expecting to append something but are using extend (which basically concatenates iterables to the list whose extend method you are calling), that could be your issue. But maybe it's just a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Sorry, that should be append.  I changed it to extend for a test.  Editing the post now.

Comment: Ah, great. I'll take a crack at it. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I edited the body with a request of the same date range, not broken out that returns yearMonth properly.  This is quite a weird bug to me...

Comment: Don't think I know enough about the GA/Pandas integration to really help you, but I doubt list.append() is the problem. You could double check that by assigning the result of the ga_read() call to a variable and then printing that variable before then appending it to your list. You'll probably see the same mangled dates. Is the problem literally only with the first date range, or are there other problem dates? If there's a pattern around the dates, that could be a clue.

Comment: Yes the problem seems to correct it self when 2013 date ranges are reached.  I believe this to be a pandas issue, so I just submitted something on github.  Thanks for trying!